# FAB 2 coloured icon

Tags: android, kotlin, floating-action-button

I am using a FAB widget and I want to add a 2 coloured icon in it. Is that possible?  This is my current code right now:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/notificationFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            android:tintMode="multiply"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:tint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/active_notif_final"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            />
```

I did a workaround: made the colors of the icon light and added tintMode as multiply to get the original color. But it still doesn't look good.

**workaround**

[image: Workaround]

**Original**

[image: Original]

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/notificationFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            app:icon="@drawable/active_notif_final"
            app:iconTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            app:iconTintMode="multiply"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            />
```

**with extended FAB:**

[image]

Comment: I propose to use ExtendedFloatingActionButton
it has a better implementation for icons and text so maybe that will help you

Comment: Okay, but I'm not able to resize it. Is there any way to resize it?

Comment: it has a attribute app:iconSize="30dp"

Comment: but I want the icon size to remain same. I just want to decrease the size of the extendedFAB

Comment: @GranitBerisha Please look at my edited question. It's giving the same result with extendedFAB and I have to use tintMode as multiply in order to get it near the original color. Also i'm unable to resize the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `icon` (`app:srcCompat`) is tinted with the `app:tint` color as per the `FloatingActionButton` documentation.

You can disable this behavior by adding `app:tint="@null"` to your fab:

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/..."
      app:tint="@null"
      .../>
```

In the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` the `app:icon` is tinted with the `app:iconTint`:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    app:icon="@drawable/...."
    app:iconTint="@null"
    .../>
```